# Handling gesture conflicts between PageView and InteractiveViewer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

In my Flutter application, I'm using both `PageView` and `InteractiveViewer` to display and interact with images. I've encountered an issue where, after zooming into an image using `InteractiveViewer`, if I try to drag the image, the page switches immediately. This behavior seems to be due to a gesture conflict between `PageView` and `InteractiveViewer`.

**What I've tried:**

- I've looked into the gestures of both widgets to see if there's a way to prioritize one over the other.
- I've checked the following StackOverflow post which suggests executing paging only when the image is not zoomed in: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748389/interactiveviewer-inside-pageview). However, this is not the behavior I want.

**Expected Behavior:** Even when the image is zoomed in, I want the application to switch to the next page only if I drag to the very edge of the zoomed image.

**Actual Behavior:** Currently, after zooming in, any drag gesture immediately switches the page.

Any suggestions or solutions to handle this gesture conflict would be greatly appreciated.

**What I was expecting:**

- I wanted a solution where, even when the image is zoomed in using `InteractiveViewer`, the application would switch to the next page only if I drag to the very edge of the zoomed image.
- Instead of the current behavior where, after zooming in, any drag gesture immediately switches the page.

mycode:

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:preload_page_view/preload_page_view.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'PhotoView + Interactiveviewer',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const GalleryExample(),
    );
  }
}

class GalleryExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const GalleryExample({super.key});

  @override
  _GalleryExampleState createState() => _GalleryExampleState();
}

class _GalleryExampleState extends State<GalleryExample> {
  late int selectedIndex;
  final TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();
  late TapDownDetails _doubleTapDetails;

  List<String> pageItems = [
    "https://user0514.cdnw.net/shared/img/thumb/12redsugar721_TP_V.jpg",
    "https://user0514.cdnw.net/shared/img/thumb/05redsugar721_TP_V.jpg"
  ];

  void _handleDoubleTap() {
    print("double tap");
    final currentScale = _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
    if (currentScale > 1.0) {
      _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity();
    } else {
      final position = _doubleTapDetails.localPosition;
      _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-position.dx, -position.dy)
        ..scale(2.0);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    pageSnapping: true,
                    reverse: true,
                    itemCount: pageItems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return LayoutBuilder(
                        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                          return InteractiveViewer(
                            maxScale: 5.0,
                            minScale: 1.0,
                            transformationController: _transformationController,
                            onInteractionEnd: (details) {
                              if (_transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis() == 1.0) {
                                _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity();
                              }
                            },
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onDoubleTapDown: (details) {
                                _doubleTapDetails = details;
                              },
                              onDoubleTap: _handleDoubleTap,
                              child: Image.network(
                                pageItems[index],
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```